# Small files take up ridiculous amounts of space

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, raid1

I've setup a little server with Ubuntu. It has 2 SSDs configured in RAID1 using EXT4.

The server has a lot of websites on it: WordPress, Magento and the likes, which amount to a lot of small files.

If I look at a random WordPress folder, its size is 75.2 MB, but the disk use is 4.12 GB. I'm using Windows 10 properties to determine the sizes. The disk has Samba shares.

I must have done something terribly wrong when setting up the server, but I'm completely lost as to what.

[image: A screenshot from the linux console]

I've tried to copy the www folder from the linux server to my Windows 10 PC. On linux du is sizing it up to be 101 GB but it's only 6 GB on the Windows PC.

Why is this happening? Can I do anything to change it?

Comment: How are you determining the "size" and the "disk use"? Please be specific and edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Didn't you read the comment? Ok, then "leave closed"

Comment: I added all three methods I use; Windows Properties View, ls and du within hours of the comment.

After it was put on hold I added specific questions to the end, even though I found it to be quite clear what I was asking. Small files take too much space, why?

Answer (score 1):

How many files do you have?

Do not use Windows to determine the sizes. Use the Linux commands to determine the space used.

In particular, the command is

```
du -s /path/to/dir
```

or for easier readable output

```
du -sh /path/to/dir
```

In general, many small files will waste more disk space than a few large files, but you would need many really small files for such a ratio.

**Edit**

From the image you added (please use text in the future), it seems you have the ext4 option `bigalloc` set for an allocation size of 1M.

> bigalloc
>
> This  ext4  feature enables clustered block allocation, so that the unit of allocation is a power of two number of blocks.  That is, each bit in the what had traditionally been known as the block allocation bitmap now indicates whether a cluster is in use or not, where a cluster is by default composed of 16 blocks.  This feature can decrease the time spent on doing block allocation and brings smaller fragmentation, especially for large files.  The size can be specified using the mke2fs -C option.

Comment: It's very bad even for a few files. I've edited my question and added a screenshot of 5 files that should be < 200 KB but is using 4.1 MB.

Comment: It seems you have bigalloc set.

Comment: Is it possible to change it, so it wouldn't be set?

Comment: It might be changeable with `tune2fs`, but I found no reference to `bigalloc` in the man page.

Comment: I'm using dumpe2fs to get the details of the filesystem. The feature list is; has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum.

Shouldn't bigalloc be on this list?